# how to share via Google+ from mobile app in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, android-fragments

How to share via Google plus in android, Kindly send the code and  details.

```
Intent gplus = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(MainActivity.this)
        .setText("This site has lots of great information about  Android!http://www.android.com")
        .setType("text/plain")
        .getIntent()
        .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");

 startActivity(gplus);
```

I tried to perform share via google plus in android  using the above code..but my application gets crashed when i run this...kindly help me to execute..

Answer (score 0):

Try to run in mobile device. If you run your app in emulator, there is no google-play services library. So run your app in real device.

Comment: be sure that your app contains google play services library and your device contains google play services apk installed

Comment: what does google play services library mean..?? how to install this apk...kindly guide me with tutorial or links or code...am totally new to android...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code...

// Launch the Google+ share dialog with attribution to your app.

```
 Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                      .setType("text/plain")
                      .setText("YOUR TEXT HERE")
                      .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("YOUR LINK HERE"))
                      .getIntent();

                  startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
```